# Ler e gravar em um arquivo .txt no php sem usar BD [Resolvido]

Tags: php, javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou criando um sistema de chat para implementar em um projeto, e estou com dificuldades em gravar e resgatar dentro de um arquivo **.txt**, quando escrevo manualmente no arquivo ele abre, só não estou conseguindo gravar pelo sistema, e no console do html não aparece erros

segue os códigos criados.

Index.js

```
function tempo(){

    setInterval(ler,3000);

};

function ler(){

    $("#conversa").load("ler.php");


             }; 

function escrever(){

    var mensagens = "textarea"; 
    var usuario = "imput:text"; 
    $.ajax({    type:"POST",
        url:"escrever.php",
        data:{"mensagens":mensagens, "usuario":usuario},
        success:function(){
            ler();
        }});}
```

escrever.php

```
<?php 



$file = file_get_contents("chat.txt");

$mensagens = "<b>" $_POST['usuario']. "</b> diz: ".$_POST['mensagens']."<br>";
$file = file_put_contents("chat.txt", $file; $mensagens);



?>
```

ler.php

```
<?php


    $file = file_get_contents("chat.txt");
    print $file;

?>
```

Comment: Esse var usuario = "imput:text"; escrito errado, já testou?

Comment: meu input no index esta assim:  <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"/>
ai coloquei assim : var usuario = "text";  seria isso ?

Comment: Não, você escreveu input com m... Corrige isso e joga no console ou um alert pra ver se ele está pegando o texto ai...

Comment: mesmo assim esta dando erro, depois q respondi percebi o erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize as funções `fopen` e `fwrite`.

```
<?php

$meu_arquivo = 'seuArquivo.txt';
$handle = fopen($meu_arquivo, 'a') or die('Erro ao abrir o arquivo:  '.$meu_arquivo);
$texto = 'texto 1 ';
fwrite($handle, $texto);
$texto_novo = "\r\n".'texto 2';
fwrite($handle, $texto_novo);

?>
```

**EDITADO**

Para testar criei estes 2 arquivos no mesmo diretório, ao abrir a página index.php os dados serão enviados via post e um alerta será exibido confirmando o envio, então pode verificar no mesmo diretório onde esta estes dois arquivos php que o arquivo `seuArquivo.txt` estará criado:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function escrever(){
            var mensagens = $('textarea#mensagens').val();  
            var usuario = $('#text').val();
            $.ajax({    type:"POST",
                url:"escrever.php",
                data:{"mensagens":mensagens, "usuario":usuario},
                success:function(){
                    alert("Dados enviados");
                }
            });
        }
        escrever();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**escrever.php**

```
<?php
    $mensagens = "<b>".$_POST['usuario']. "</b> diz: ".$_POST['mensagens']."<br>";
    $meu_arquivo = 'seuArquivo.txt';
    $handle = fopen($meu_arquivo, 'a') or die('Erro ao abrir o arquivo:  '.$meu_arquivo);
    fwrite($handle, $mensagens);
?>
```

Comment: vou tentar amigo

Comment: ficaria assim : <pre><code>   <?php $file = 'chat.txt'; $handle = fopen($fiile, 'a') or die('Erro ao abrir o arquivo: '.$file); $mensagens = "<b>" $_POST['usuario']. "</b> diz: ".$_POST['mensagens']."<br>"; fwrite($handle, $mensagens); $texto_novo = "\r\n".'texto 2'; fwrite($handle, $texto_novo); ?> <code>

Comment: @Fabrizzio Isso, só corrigi ali em `$mensagens = "<b>" $_POST['usuario']. "</b> diz: ".$_POST['mensagens']."<br>";` você não esta concatenando o `"<br>"` com o `$_POST["usuario"].`, falou colocar um `.` entre eles.

Comment: mesmo assim não esta gravando, e não esta dando erro no console

Comment: @Fabrizzio, editei minha resposta incluindo o teste que fiz aqui, o arquivo é gerado sem problema, tente copiar o código que acabei de colocar e realizar o mesmo teste.

Comment: continua não gravando no txt amigo, aparece o spam de arquivo enviado e tudo, mas nao grava, deve ser outra coisa q não consigo te explicar, posso te madar o sistema por email?

Comment: @Fabrizzio, vixe, que bruxaria em rsrsrs. Deixa eu só confirmar uma coisa, a pasta onde você colocou os arquivos `index.php` e `escrever.php` o apache ou o nginx (depende de qual você esta usando para servir os arquivos php) tem direito de escrita nela certo? Pois talvez eles só tenham direito de leitura e não de escrita. por isso você não consegue criar arquivos nela.

Comment: @Fabrizzio, ok, esta pedindo permissão para acessar o arquivo no googledrive

Comment: eu estou usando o apache do wampserve, será q isso? tem como editar e dar permissão?

Comment: @Fabrizzio, te respondi no email, basicamente o único problema era que no arquivo **escrever.php** você deixou seu código antigo, e ele estava com erro de sintaxe, era só deixar igual eu coloquei na resposta aqui do stack.